# Switching between two Mac terminal windows

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, applescript, gnu-screen

I have an interactive bash script running in a Mac OSX bash Terminal window. I would like, from within that script, to 
open a second Terminal window, print in it the content of a variable from the script in the first window,
keep that second window open somewhere on the screen while I continue interacting with the first window, and finally
have the second window closed when I do not need it anymore.

Since I am on Mac OSX, I am thinking of using osascript to run Applescript commands opening the second window, pasting the variable content in it and returning control to the first window, but I cannot make it work.

```
#!/bin/bash

var2print="I want this to print in the text window"

osascript -e '

tell application "Terminal"
    tell window 1               # this just renames the first window
        set custom title to "Main window"
    end tell
do script                       # this opens a new window
    tell window 1
        set custom title to "Text window"
        set selected to true    # my first idea to put focus on this window
        activate                # my second idea to put focus on this window
    end tell
end tell
'
printf "%s\n" "$var2print"       # prints in main window, despite all efforts
read -sn 1 -p "Press any key to continue..."
```

Surprisingly to me, the very last command 'read' also takes place in the main window, but the focus is on the text window and I have to manually select the main window to press a key and end the script.

I have considered letting go of AppleScript and using the gnu-screen command instead, but it seems like overkill for my purpose to simply have some info displayed for a while.

Any help to better understand what's going on and to find a practical solution to switch between terminal windows would be greatly appreciated. W.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle two windows in Terminal.app with AppleScript this way

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set index of window 2 to 1
end tell
```

window 1 is always the frontmost window

Comment: Sadly, this does not work and yields the same lack of results as 'activate' and 'set selected to true'....

Comment: darn, it works flawlessly in Script Editor. BTW, `activate` doesn't affect windows at all

Answer (score 0):

How about using a dialog box to display your message and go away automagically after a few seconds like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
bashvar="ZippedyDooDah"
osascript >/dev/null 2>&1 <<EOF
tell application "System Events" to display alert "$bashvar" buttons {"OK"} as warning default button "OK" giving up after 5
EOF
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "echo hello"'
```

Or, you can set a `bash` variable like this and send that for display:

```
MSG="FreddyFrog"

osascript<<EOF
tell app "Terminal"
do script "echo $MSG"
end tell
EOF
```

If you want to send it more than one message, you could make it tell you its `tty` as the command you pass, then you will have that in a file and you can send it further messages...

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "tty > tty.txt"'
```

If you now look in the file `tty.txt` you will see the device special file of the terminal window you created, some thing like `/dev/ttys002`, then you can do this from your original window

```
echo "Some stuff" > /dev/ttys002
echo "More stuff" > /dev/ttys002
```

or, more succinctly

```
echo hello > $(cat tty.txt)
```